# At what step in a genetic algorithm should fitness sharing be applied?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am using the fitness sharing method to resolve a multimodal problem (2 max). The fitness function finds the maximum of the count of zeros and the count of ones in a individual:

```
f=max(u,(1-u))
```

where `u` is count of ones in the genotype. For example, for the genotype `101110`,

```
f=max(4,2)=4
```

The problem can be resolved with a genetic algorithm. The genetic algorithm often has 5 steps:

*Initial_Population->Fitness Evaluation->Selection->Crossover->Mutation->Fitness Evaluation*

To ensure that both peaks in this multimodal fitness landscape are found, the fitness sharing method can be added to a genetic algorithm. However, I don't know where that method is introduced in the above GA steps. Is it between mutation and fitness evaluation? And if it is right, does the fitness evaluation use raw fitness or adjusted fitness from the sharing method?

Answer (score 2):

The most intuitive way to apply fitness sharing is to factor it into **fitness evaluation by using it to adjust the raw fitness**, every time you evaluate fitness.

The inspiration for fitness sharing is that, in biology, the amount of competition that a given organism has to deal with will have a big impact on its fitness. Organisms that need to compete with many others for food will take in less energy and produce fewer offspring, i.e. their fitness will be lower. There will be heavier competition between more similar organisms.

Therefore, fitness sharing is best conceived of as an adjustment to fitness evaluation - it's essentially accounting for the fact that a solution's fitness is lower than it seems, due to "competition." Of course, in the standard genetic algorithm, this is not traditionally competition for resources. Instead, it is competition to be the best solution in a given part of the fitness landscape.

The more rigorous way to think of fitness sharing is as a process that **directly deforms the fitness landscape**, as shown in the animation below. The hills of warmer colors represent areas within the search space that have higher fitness. As such, the population rapidly gravitates towards them. However, if fitness sharing is applied, this reduces the fitness associated with these areas, forcing the population to spread out and explore more of the search space (because most locations are only good if there are just a few solutions there). Since the fitness landscape directly determines the fitness associated with each solution, this also suggests that the fitness evaluation step is the appropriate place to apply the transformation.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your explanation. Could you join the chat room. I would like to ask you more detail about it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/76953/fitness-sharing-in-ga?tab=general